# React Table displaying no result when I use setFilter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a table with a global filter and a setFilter.
The global filter works fine and filters the results except for the customField column that I have as an optional column and may or may not have data.
For the custom fields column, I want to create a separate input that filters only that column but when I type into it all the records just disappear and I get no errors, so I'm not sure what's going on.
I would really appreciate any help, thank you.

**Record Table**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  useTable,
  useFlexLayout,
  useFilters,
  useGlobalFilter
} from "react-table";
import _ from "lodash";
// noinspection ES6CheckImport
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import { useStateWithLocalStorage } from "../../hooks/useStateWithLocalStorage";

// Define a default UI for filtering
function GlobalFilter({
  preGlobalFilteredRows,
  globalFilter,
  setGlobalFilter
}) {
  return (
    <span>
      <input
        value={globalFilter || ""}
        onChange={e => {
          setGlobalFilter(e.target.value || undefined);
        }}
        placeholder={" Search By Any Field"}
        style={{
          fontSize: "2.0rem",
          width: "100%"
        }}
      />
    </span>
  );
}

function CustomFieldFilter({ filter, setFilter }) {
  return (
    <input
      value={filter || ""}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter("customFields", e.target.value || undefined);
      }}
      placeholder={`Search Custom Field`}
    />
  );
}

export const RecordTable = ({ forms }) => {
  //TODO figure out why react-table crashes if forms is not set to data variable below first
  const data = forms;
  let history = useHistory();
  const customFields = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("..."));
  let customFieldName = "";
  if (Array.isArray(customFields) && customFields.length) {
    customFieldName = customFields[0].customFieldName;
  } else {
    customFieldName = "Custom Field";
  }


  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Form Records",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Child First Name",
            id: "children",
            accessor: values => {
              let childNames = [];
              _.map(values.children, child => {
                childNames.push(child.childName);
              });
              return childNames.join(", ");
            }
          },
          {
            Header: "Time In",
            accessor: "timeIn"
          },
          {
            Header: "Time Out",
            accessor: "timeOut"
          },
          {
            Header: "Guardian Name",
            accessor: "parentName"
          },
          {
            Header: customFieldName,
            id: "customFields",
            accessor: value => {
              const customFields = value.customFields;
              if (
                Array.isArray(customFields) &&
                customFields.length &&
                customFields[0].customFieldName === customFieldName
              )
                return <div>{customFields[0].customFieldValue}</div>;
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      //Filter: CustomFieldFilter,
      minWidth: 20,
      maxWidth: 150,
      width: 120
    }),
    []
  );

  const openViewDisclaimerPage = rowObject => {
    console.log(rowObject.original);
    history.push("/viewform", { ...rowObject.original });
  };

  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setFilter,
    setGlobalFilter
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn
    },
    useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter,
    useFlexLayout
  );

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Records: {rows.length}</div>
      <GlobalFilter
        preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
        globalFilter={state.globalFilter}
        setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
      />
      <CustomFieldFilter filter={state.filter} setFilter={setFilter} />

      <div
        style={{
          height: 500,
          border: "2px solid grey",
          borderRadius: "5px",
          overflow: "scroll"
        }}>
        <Table striped bordered hover responsive={"md"} {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>

          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <tr
                  {...row.getRowProps({
                    onClick: () => openViewDisclaimerPage(row)
                  })}>
                  {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return (
                      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a quick recording of whats happening.

[image]

Comment: it looks like `setFilter` takes a `columnId` as the first parameter, unless I'm missing something

Comment: @Anthony thanks for your reply. I actually have done that. “customFields” is the first parameter of setFilter, if you look at the customFieldFilter function,

Comment: ah yes I see now, my bad; I was expecting a numeric id in my head for some reason